# What does it mean when the last digits of an IP address change?

Tags: ip, ipv4, network, ip-address

So in a case where I have an IP address, 162.158.68.xxx, what is happening when those values in xxx change?

I ask because I'm looking at requests going through to my application's server and one of the origins is 162.158.68.62 and the next 2 minutes later is 162.158.68.63 (the example network numbers aren't the real numbers I'm working with, but the last digits are).

I'm trying to understand what's happening, because I'm noticing a pattern in duplicate transactions on my application, and the transactions all originate from 2 IP addresses with only the last digits being different.

Comment: I's really impossible to say for sure.  You haven't provided much information There is nothing special about the last digits of the IP address.  To computers, they're just 32-bit numbers.  Most likely, hey are different sources.  But application issues are off-topic here.

Comment: @RonTrunk I thought I kept my question pretty specific to the context of the IP address itself. Just because I'm trying to debug an application, doesn't make understanding the construction and behavior of a changing IP address less relevant... I read elsewhere that the first 6 numbers are typically derived from the network, while the last 6 are derived in some capacity from the host. Is this incorrect information? I'm trying to understand in what scenario why only one number would increment in the span of only a couple minutes between network requests. Please advise if this is still irrelevant

Comment: Your information is inaccurate . IP addresses are 32 bit numbers. The decimal digits are just a way of making addresses easier to read for humans.  You can’t assume network and host portions from them.

Comment: See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how IPv4 addressing and subnetting work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get some information about who those IPs belong to it would probably help you out. Odds are they are different hosts, but they could also be devices that pulled a new DHCP lease or changed IPs while you were monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Probably they are from two different hosts. But if the host is using IP NAT pool then those two IPs could be from the two different hosts.